# redirected you too many times. in prestashop 1.7 on subdomain

Tags: redirect, server, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am facing an issue with Prestashop 1.7 setup on server

Error is :

**This page isn’t working**
**subdomain.domain.com** redirected you too many times.

Try clearing your cookies.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be for many reasons.

The most common of these is the incorrect setting of the SSL redirection in the host and the domains in the "SEO and URLs" section in the BO